# Copy images from a PDF in powershell

Tags: powershell, pdf, adobe, acrobat

I am trying to play around with Adobe Acrobat comobjects, my end-goal is to make something that will copy images from a PDF and insert them into an excel sheet. I tried opening the PDF in word and it appears that the pictures are actually grouped shapes that are not positioned correctly when opened in word. I have discovered a CopyToClipboard method, but I am not entirely sure how to call it properly and so far my attempts to test it yield nothing actually in the clipboard. Can anyone guide me or offer any resources I can consult?

So far I have:

```
$testfile = PDF_OF_INTEREST.PDF

$app = New-Object -ComObject AcroExch.App

$PDDoc = New-Object -ComObject AcroExch.PDDoc

$PDDoc.Open($testfile)
$AVDoc = $PDDoc.OpenAVDoc($testfile)

$frame = $avdoc.getframe()
$view = $avdoc.GetAVPageView()
$page3 = $view.goto(3)

write-host "Page num: " $view.getpageNum()

$page = $view.GetPage()


#I tried this and while it does not yield an error, clipboard is not affected
$clippy = $page.copytoclipboard($page, 0, 10, 1)

#Maybe this will work???
$clippy | Out-file PDF_OF_INTEREST.docx

#No, that didn't work either
```

Comment: I wrote a [function](https://github.com/krzydoug/Tools/blob/master/Get-ImagesFromPdf.ps1) that extracts images from PDF files. Based on the answer [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/ca9a2155-a1ed-4f89-9749-4743038ff381/how-to-extract-images-from-pdf-file-using-powershell?forum=winserverpowershell) which utilizes an [open source tool](http://www.xpdfreader.com/index.html)

Comment: Extracting the images from a PDF file can be done directly using a library that is able to parse the PDF data and present its components in a usable form. You could consider using something like the [LEADTOOLS PDFDocument class](https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/v21/dh/pdf/pdfdocument.html) which is able to parse text, images, shapes, links, annotations, form fields, and signatures. Disclaimer: I am an employee of the vendor of these Cloud Services.